# How to find if nth value is smaller than the previous n-1 values

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table with the following schema:

```
Order_id    customer_Id purchaseDate    movie_Id    minutesStreamed
01  C1  1/1/2000    P1  100
02  C2  1/1/2002    P2  90
03  C3  4/1/2002    P3  93
04  C4  4/1/2003    P1  99
05  C4  1/1/2006    P2  99
06  C1  5/1/2006    P5  89
07  C4  12/1/2017   P5  89
08  C3  3/3/2018    P1  145
09  C4  3/3/2018    P6  147
```

I want to find those customers who watch less and less minutes each time they watch a movie i.e. their second streaming is less than 1st, and their 3rd is less than their 2nd and so on and so forth.

I know how to find for one case i.e. 3rd <2rd or 2nd<1st but how to check for all combinations.

```
select a.*
from
(
select customer_id,purchase_date,minutes_streamed, lag(minutes_streamed,1) over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_date) prev_mins_streams
from orders
)a
inner join
(select customer_id,max(purchase_date) max_purchase_dt from orders group by customer_id) b
on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
and a.purchase_date=b.max_purchase_dt
where a.minutes_streamed<a.prev_mins_streams
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need customers who only decline, define a flag and then aggregate the flat:

```
select o.customer_id
from (select o.*,
             lag(minutes_streamed,1) over (partition by customer_id order by purchase_date) as prev_ms
      from orders o
     ) o
group by o.customer_id
having sum(case when prev_ms is null or prev_ms < minutes_streams then 0 else 1 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause basically counts the exceptions.  The `= 0` says there are none.